# Green's function of a Laplacian on a Torus does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, greens-function

Green's function of a Laplacian on a Torus does not exist?

My answer is No, it does not exist. Appreciate your help If I am wrong.

Comment: Try this link https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523238/greens-function-on-torus

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks for the comment. The answer there confirms non existence. (but there is an extra constant term in that). Nevertheless it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: It really depends what you mean by it doesn't exist. The Laplacian operator is not invertible since the kernel is nontrivial. However, if you remove all the constant functions then it's okay.